# How to pass a cell content that is an array of strings to a function as parameter?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, arguments

I've this VBA UDF that properly returns an array of strings:

```
Function SplitString(ByVal Str As String, ByVal StrLen As Integer) As String()
    Dim ArrStrs() As String
    Dim ArrCount As Integer
    ReDim ArrStrs((Len(Str) - 1) \ StrLen)
    ArrCount = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(Str) Step StrLen
        ArrStrs(ArrCount) = Mid(Str, i, StrLen)
        ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
    Next

    SplitString = ArrStrs
End Function
```

I used the above function in a cell of a Excel sheet, say the cell `A1`

```
=SplitString("wordexample";2)
```

Which shows

[image]

And, by entering the edit mode of the cell and clicking F9, it shows

[image]

Now, I want to pass the content of `A1` to another UDF as argument named `ArrayOfStrs`.

I tried these and some others:

```
Function MyFunct(ArrayOfStrs As Variant, ParamArray CStrs() As Variant)
'Using Function MyFunct(ArrayOfStrs As String, ParamArray CStrs() As Variant) I get #VALUE! error

    MsgBox ArrayOfStrs(1)   'returns "wo"
    'MsgBox ArrayOfStrs(2)   returns ""
    'MsgBox ArrayOfStrs(...) returns ""

End Function
```

But I can not get the `ArrayOfStrs` as array of strings. That is, only the first value (`wo`) of the previously splitted string seems to be passed to `MyFunct`. In fact, only the `ArrayOfStrs(1)` works (it returns `wo`) and the other values (`rd`, `ex`, `am`, `pl` and `e`) seems to be not available in `ArrayOfStrs`.

How to correctly pass `ArrayOfStrs` to `MyFunct` as function argument?

Comment: Would help to show an example of how you actually pass the array, in addition to the `MyFunct` function header.

Comment: @AAA I can not call `SplitString` from within `MyFunct`.

Comment: @TimWilliams Is it possible to return the full array from `SplitString` to populate the `A1` cell? If so, how to make that? BTW Why `A1` contains only the first element?

Comment: A cell can only have one value = even if you enter (eg) `={"one","two"}` it will just display "one" and `TypeName(Selection.Value)` will be "string".  You'd have to do something like return a single delimited value which could then be `Split()` in `MyFunct`

Answer (score 4):

You could `Evaluate` the contents of `A1`, where `A1` contains your formula as mentioned in your question:

```
Function myFunct(myRange As Range)
    Dim ArrayOfStrs As Variant
    Dim msg As String
    Dim I As Long
ArrayOfStrs = Evaluate(myRange.Formula)

msg = ""
For I = LBound(ArrayOfStrs) To UBound(ArrayOfStrs)
    msg = msg & vbLf & ArrayOfStrs(I)
Next I

msg = Mid(msg, 2)

MsgBox msg

End Function
```

But there's no need to put `SplitString` on the worksheet to get the result:

```
Function myFunct2()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim msg As String

arr = SplitString("wordexample", 2)
msg = ""
For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    msg = msg & vbLf & arr(I)
Next I

msg = Mid(msg, 2)

MsgBox msg

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `myRange.Parent.Evaluate(myRange.Formula)` assuming everything is on the same sheet, otherwise results may be off when some other sheet is active.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, and there's a lot of testing that would need to be done to ensure processing of something valid.  And, although it works, it seems an awkward solution to me. I don't understand why the OP cannot use `myFunct2` or some variation.  But without knowing the real problem, it's hard to craft a good solution. So this answer is presented more as a concept, and not as something that should be used in distributed code.